# OpenERP server addons crm module fails

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I'm trying to resolve an issue that I have with openerp CRM module which isn't loading. I was working fine at some point. After making some changes to a report it stopped working with the error, "The report "report.crm.case" already exist!" Starting openerp-server in debug mode gives me this:

```
`postgres@nodesoft-dev:/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server$ /usr/bin/python2.5 ./openerp-server.py -dnodesoft --update=all --stop-after-init --log-level=debug --addons-path=/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/addons/

[2011-11-09 03:00:14,301] DEBUG:psycopg2:installed. Logging using Python logging module

[2011-11-09 03:00:14,301] INFO:server:version - 5.0.6

[2011-11-09 03:00:14,301] INFO:server:addons_path - /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/addons

[2011-11-09 03:00:14,301] INFO:server:database hostname - localhost

[2011-11-09 03:00:14,301] INFO:server:database port - 5432

[2011-11-09 03:00:14,301] INFO:server:database user - postgres

[2011-11-09 03:00:14,305] INFO:objects:initialising distributed objects services

[2011-11-09 03:00:14,477] INFO:dbpool:Connecting to nodesoft

[2011-11-09 03:00:14,489] INFO:init:module base: loading objects

[2011-11-09 03:00:14,493] INFO:init:module base: registering objects

[2011-11-09 03:00:14,605] INFO:init:module base: creating or updating database tables

[2011-11-09 03:00:15,633] INFO:init:module base: loading base_data.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:15,857] INFO:init:module base: loading base_menu.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:15,893] INFO:init:module base: loading security/base_security.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:15,929] INFO:init:module base: loading res/res_security.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:15,937] INFO:init:module base: loading maintenance/maintenance_security.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:15,945] INFO:init:module base: loading base_update.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:16,013] INFO:init:module base: loading ir/wizard/wizard_menu_view.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:16,025] INFO:init:module base: loading ir/ir.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:16,653] INFO:init:module base: loading ir/workflow/workflow_view.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:16,757] INFO:init:module base: loading module/module_wizard.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:16,813] INFO:init:module base: loading module/module_view.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:16,893] INFO:init:module base: loading module/module_data.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:16,905] INFO:init:module base: loading module/module_report.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:16,909] INFO:init:module base: loading res/res_request_view.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:16,965] INFO:init:module base: loading res/res_lang_view.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:16,993] INFO:init:module base: loading res/partner/partner_report.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:16,997] INFO:init:module base: loading res/partner/partner_view.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:17,217] INFO:init:module base: loading res/partner/partner_wizard.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:17,221] INFO:init:module base: loading res/bank_view.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:17,245] INFO:init:module base: loading res/country_view.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:17,285] INFO:init:module base: loading res/res_currency_view.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:17,305] INFO:init:module base: loading res/partner/crm_view.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:17,369] INFO:init:module base: loading res/partner/partner_data.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:17,381] INFO:init:module base: loading res/ir_property_view.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:17,409] INFO:init:module base: loading security/base_security.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:17,449] INFO:init:module base: loading maintenance/maintenance_view.xml

[2011-11-09 03:00:17,485] INFO:init:module base: loading security/ir.model.access.csv

[2011-11-09 03:00:18,085] INFO:i18n:module base: loading translation file for language ro_RO

[2011-11-09 03:00:24,365] INFO:init:updating modules list

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,037] WARNING:init:module google_earth: module not found

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,037] WARNING:init:module google_earth: module not found

sh: bzr: command not found

sh: lsb_release: command not found

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,077] ERROR:init:[01]:

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,077] ERROR:init:[02]: Environment Information :

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,077] ERROR:init:[03]: System : Linux-2.6.26-2-xen-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-5.0.4

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,077] ERROR:init:[04]: OS Name : posix

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,077] ERROR:init:[05]: Operating System Release : 2.6.26-2-xen-amd64

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,077] ERROR:init:[06]: Operating System Version : #1 SMP Wed Jan 13 00:12:41 UTC 2010

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,077] ERROR:init:[07]: Operating System Architecture : 64bit

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,077] ERROR:init:[08]: Operating System Locale : en_US.ISO8859-1

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,077] ERROR:init:[09]: Python Version : 2.5.2

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,077] ERROR:init:[10]: OpenERP-Server Version : 5.0.6

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,077] ERROR:init:[11]: Last revision No. & ID :

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,077] ERROR:init:[12]: module stock: Unmet dependencies: account

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,077] WARNING:init:Not all modules have loaded.

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,077] DEBUG:init:Updating graph with 18 more modules

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,153] INFO:init:module base: loading objects

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,209] INFO:init:module base_setup: loading objects

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,209] INFO:init:module base_setup: registering objects

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,213] INFO:init:module base_setup: creating or updating database tables

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,213] INFO:init:module process: loading objects

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,213] INFO:init:module process: registering objects

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,217] INFO:init:module process: creating or updating database tables

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,281] INFO:init:module board: loading objects

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,281] INFO:init:module board: registering objects

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,285] INFO:init:module board: creating or updating database tables

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,321] INFO:init:module google_map: loading objects

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,321] INFO:init:module google_map: registering objects

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,321] INFO:init:module google_map: creating or updating database tables

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,353] INFO:init:module crm: loading objects

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,353] INFO:init:module crm: registering objects

sh: bzr: command not found

sh: lsb_release: command not found

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,377] CRITICAL:init:[01]:

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,377] CRITICAL:init:[02]: Environment Information :

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,377] CRITICAL:init:[03]: System : Linux-2.6.26-2-xen-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-5.0.4

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,377] CRITICAL:init:[04]: OS Name : posix

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,377] CRITICAL:init:[05]: Operating System Release : 2.6.26-2-xen-amd64

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,377] CRITICAL:init:[06]: Operating System Version : #1 SMP Wed Jan 13 00:12:41 UTC 2010

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,377] CRITICAL:init:[07]: Operating System Architecture : 64bit

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,377] CRITICAL:init:[08]: Operating System Locale : en_US.ISO8859-1

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,377] CRITICAL:init:[09]: Python Version : 2.5.2

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,377] CRITICAL:init:[10]: OpenERP-Server Version : 5.0.6

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,377] CRITICAL:init:[11]: Last revision No. & ID :

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,377] CRITICAL:init:[12]: Couldn't load module crm

sh: bzr: command not found

sh: lsb_release: command not found

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,397] CRITICAL:init:[01]:

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,397] CRITICAL:init:[02]: Environment Information :

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,397] CRITICAL:init:[03]: System : Linux-2.6.26-2-xen-amd64-x86_64-with-debian-5.0.4

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,397] CRITICAL:init:[04]: OS Name : posix

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,397] CRITICAL:init:[05]: Operating System Release : 2.6.26-2-xen-amd64

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,401] CRITICAL:init:[06]: Operating System Version : #1 SMP Wed Jan 13 00:12:41 UTC 2010

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,401] CRITICAL:init:[07]: Operating System Architecture : 64bit

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,401] CRITICAL:init:[08]: Operating System Locale : en_US.ISO8859-1

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,401] CRITICAL:init:[09]: Python Version : 2.5.2

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,401] CRITICAL:init:[10]: OpenERP-Server Version : 5.0.6

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,401] CRITICAL:init:[11]: Last revision No. & ID :

[2011-11-09 03:00:27,401] CRITICAL:init:[12]: The report "report.crm.case" already exist!

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "./openerp-server.py", line 111, in <module>

pooler.get_db_and_pool(db, update_module=tools.config['init'] or tools.config['update'])

File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/pooler.py", line 40, in get_db_and_pool

addons.load_modules(db, force_demo, status, update_module)

File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/addons/__init__.py", line 728, in load_modules

r = load_module_graph(cr, graph, status, report=report)

File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/addons/__init__.py", line 578, in load_module_graph

register_class(package.name)

File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/addons/__init__.py", line 400, in register_class

imp.load_module(m, *fm)

File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/addons/crm/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>

import report

File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/addons/crm/report/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>

'addons/crm/report/case.rml', parser=order, header=True)

File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/report/report_sxw.py", line 329, in __init__

report_rml.__init__(self, name, table, rml, '')

File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/report/interface.py", line 74, in __init__

super(report_rml, self).__init__(name)

File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/openerp-server/report/interface.py", line 52, in __init__

assert not netsvc.service_exist(name), 'The report "%s" already exist!' % name

AssertionError: The report "report.crm.case" already exist!`
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error, because you have two copies of same report

Answer (score 0):

I think I've gotten that error when I copy and paste an existing report parser, and then forget to rename the copy.

If you search your source code for the string "report.crm.case", you'll probably find it in two places.

Comment: Heloo. Thanks for your answer. I've looked into addons folder and searched for "report.crm.case" in each file using "find + grep" and I have more then 4000 findings. In the /addons/crm dir I have this folder named "report" where there are my xml, rml, xsl files. Could you help me further please ? Where exactly I should look for duplicates? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure how you found more than 4000, but here are two ways you could find more than one. If you don't escape the `.`, it will match any character, like `report_crm_case`. If you don't include a quote at the end, then it will find other related reports like `report.crm.case.section.stage`. Here's the find command I used to find exactly one instance: `find . -type f -path *.py -exec grep -rHn "report\.crm\.case['\"]" {} \;`

Comment: I think I figured out how you found 4000 matches. You probably were seeing all `.po` files in the translation folders. Restricting `find` to `.py` files eliminates those.

Comment: Hello again. Thank you for your answer and kind help. I've refined my search and I found only 3 encounters: find . -type f -exec grep -rHn "report\.crm\.case['\"]" {} \;./crm/report/report_businessopp.py:177:report_custom('report.crm.case')
./crm/report/__init__.py:44:report_sxw.report_sxw('report.crm.case', 'crm.case',
./crm/report/__init__.py:50:report_sxw.report_sxw('report.crm.case', 'crm.case',

Comment: Looking at /addons/crm/report/report/__init__.py file, I have: import report_businessopp


from report import report_sxw



class order(report_sxw.rml_parse):

    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):

        super(order, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context)

        self.localcontext.update({

            'time': time,

        })



report_sxw.report_sxw('report.crm.case', 'crm.case',

      'addons/crm/report/case.rml', parser=order, header=True)



#report_sxw.report_sxw('report.crm.case', 'crm.case',
#
#      'addons/crm/report/statistics.rml', parser=order, header=True)

Comment: Not sure here is the problem, I've commented line 50 and tried again to start server, but unfortunately same error occurred :(

Comment: Why have you got any code in your `__init__.py` file, @user10367? The official branch for 5.0.6 has one line: `import report_businessopp`. Even if you comment out line 50, you've still got a conflict between line 44 and the one in the `report_businessopp.py` file. Each report has to have a unique name across the whole database.

Comment: Don Kikby, thank for your answer. How do I check in database for reports? I think the problem is in db because I'm using an older db dump. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, @user10367, I should have said it must be unique across the whole code base. That is, you can't have the same report name in another module. If you think the old database is causing problems, do a migration. (Look in the File menu under Databases.)